# Slicing tensors in tensorflow using argmax

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make a dynamic loss function in tensorflow. I want to calculate the energy of a signal's FFT, more specifically only a window of size 3 around the most dominant peak. I am unable to implement in TF, as it throws a lot of errors like `Stride` and `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1,64], [1,64], and [1] instead.`

My code is this:

```
self.spec = tf.fft(self.signal)
self.spec_mag = tf.complex_abs(self.spec[:,1:33])
self.argm = tf.cast(tf.argmax(self.spec_mag, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
self.frac = tf.reduce_sum(self.spec_mag[self.argm-1:self.argm+2], 1)
```

Since I am computing batchwise of 64 and dimension of data as 64 too, the shape of `self.signal` is `(64,64)`. I wish to calculate only the AC components of the FFT. As the signal is real valued, only half the spectrum would do the job. Hence, the shape of `self.spec_mag` is `(64,32)`.

The max in this fft is located at `self.argm` which has a shape `(64,1)`.

Now I want to calculate the energy of 3 elements around the max peak via: `self.spec_mag[self.argm-1:self.argm+2]`.

However when I run the code and try to obtain the value of `self.frac`, I get thrown with multiple errors.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you were missing and index when accessing argm. Here is the fixed version of the 1, 64 version.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(1, 64)
xt = tf.constant(value=x, dtype=tf.complex64)

signal = xt
print('signal', signal.shape)
print('signal', signal.eval())

spec = tf.fft(signal)
print('spec', spec.shape)
print('spec', spec.eval())

spec_mag = tf.abs(spec[:,1:33])
print('spec_mag', spec_mag.shape)
print('spec_mag', spec_mag.eval())

argm = tf.cast(tf.argmax(spec_mag, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
print('argm', argm.shape)
print('argm', argm.eval())

frac = tf.reduce_sum(spec_mag[0][(argm[0]-1):(argm[0]+2)], 0)
print('frac', frac.shape)
print('frac', frac.eval())
```

and here is the expanded version (batch, m, n)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(1, 1, 64)
xt = tf.constant(value=x, dtype=tf.complex64)

signal = xt
print('signal', signal.shape)
print('signal', signal.eval())

spec = tf.fft(signal)
print('spec', spec.shape)
print('spec', spec.eval())

spec_mag = tf.abs(spec[:, :, 1:33])
print('spec_mag', spec_mag.shape)
print('spec_mag', spec_mag.eval())

argm = tf.cast(tf.argmax(spec_mag, 2), dtype=tf.int32)
print('argm', argm.shape)
print('argm', argm.eval())

frac = tf.reduce_sum(spec_mag[0][0][(argm[0][0]-1):(argm[0][0]+2)], 0)
print('frac', frac.shape)
print('frac', frac.eval())
```

you may want to fix function names since I edit this code at a newer version of tensorflow.

Comment: `spec_mag[0][0]` ensures that you find the max only for the first batch, first slice. OP wants it across all batches and slices.

Comment: You've taken `batch=1` and `m=1`, but your code won't hold for the general case. Especially if one were to set `batch` to `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow indexing uses [tf.Tensor.getitem](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__):

> This operation extracts the specified region from the tensor. The notation is similar to NumPy with the restriction that currently only support basic indexing. That means that using a tensor as input is not currently allowed

So using `tf.slice` and `tf.strided_slice` is out of the question as well.

Whereas in `tf.gather` `indices` defines slices into the first dimension of `Tensor`, in `tf.gather_nd`, `indices` defines slices into the first `N` dimensions of the `Tensor`, where `N = indices.shape[-1]`

Since you wanted the 3 values around the `max`, I manually extract the first, second and third element using a list comprehension, followed be a `tf.stack`

```
import tensorflow as tf

signal = tf.placeholder(shape=(64, 64), dtype=tf.complex64)
spec = tf.fft(signal)
spec_mag = tf.abs(spec[:,1:33])
argm = tf.cast(tf.argmax(spec_mag, 1), dtype=tf.int32)

frac = tf.stack([tf.gather_nd(spec,tf.transpose(tf.stack(
             [tf.range(64), argm+i]))) for i in [-1, 0, 1]])

frac = tf.reduce_sum(frac, 1)
```

This will fail for the corner case where `argm` is the first or last element in the row, but it should be easy to resolve.

Comment: I am unable to use `tf.stack` as I am stuck with TF 0.12. Is there any other alternative?